# Syntactic analysis of the sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I can't quite understand how to make a syntactic analysis of the following sentence:

> He decided that he would make sure that their promise came true.

Comment: So I take it that you are concerned about the fact that it contains two declarative content clauses, one embedded within the other: "that he would make sure that their promise came true" is the larger clause functioning as complement of "decided", and "that their promise came true" is the smaller one embedded within the first and functioning as complement of "sure".